# getting a json object with array images return unexpected end of json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, backend

I am sure it has been handled before, but I have not been able to find another answer to the situation from google. When I use postman to get a route, it returns the following errors:

1. [0] SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON inpu
   [0]at JSON.parse ()
   [0]at model.get (C:\Users\EA_Ma\Desktop\App-projects\majeksCorp\models\Services.js:55:23)
   [0] at model.get (C:\Users\EA_Ma\Desktop\App-projects\majeksCorp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:3465:41)
   [0] at model.get (C:\Users\EA_Ma\Desktop\App-projects\majeksCorp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:3499:33)
   [0] at model.toJSON (C:\Users\EA_Ma\Desktop\App-projects\majeksCorp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:4368:12)
   [0] at JSON.stringify ()
   [0] at stringify (C:\Users\EA_Ma\Desktop\App-projects\majeksCorp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1123:12)
   [0] at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\EA_Ma\Desktop\App-projects\majeksCorp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:260:14)
   [0] at C:\Users\EA_Ma\Desktop\App-projects\majeksCorp\routes\api\services.js:179:30
   [0] at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

This is the affected schema:

```
     "use script";
     module.exports = (sequelize, Datatypes) => {return sequelize.define("service",{
    id: {
    type: Datatypes.UUID,
    primaryKey: true,
    defaultValue: Datatypes.UUIDV4,

  title: {
    type: Datatypes.STRING,
    required: true,
    allowNull: true,
  },
  category: {
    type: Datatypes.STRING,
    required: true,
    allowNull: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: Datatypes.STRING,
    required: true,
    allowNull: true,
  },
  picture: {
    type: Datatypes.STRING,
  },
  service_gallery: {
    type: Datatypes.STRING,
    defaultValue: null,
    get: function () {
      return JSON.parse(this.getDataValue("service_gallery"));
    },
    set: function (val) {
      return this.setDataValue("service_gallery", JSON.stringify(val));
    },
    allowNull: true,
  },
  date: {
    //Exakt den datum som personen registrera sig
    type: Datatypes.DATE,
    defaultValue: Datatypes.NOW,
  },

  //This is the columns or database
  updated_at: { type: Datatypes.DATE },
  deleted_at: { type: Datatypes.DATE },
  },

  {
  underscored: true, //This is created for it
  paranoid: true, //Database won't really delete information from database.
  }
  );
  };
```

This was the method I called.

```
router.get("/:category/:title", async(req, res) => {
 const errors = {};
 await db.service.findOne({
    where: {[Op.and]: [{category: req.params.category}, {title: req.params.title}]}
  })
  .then((service) => {
  if (!service) {
    errors.noservice = "Nothing was found";
    res.status(404).json(errors);
    return; 
    }
    if(service) return res.json(service);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    });
```

I think the error is originating from this line in the Schema:
return JSON.parse(this.getDataValue("service_gallery"));

Comment: Are you certain you need to use json.parse? Check the output of this.getDataValue("service_gallery") and check if it's a stringed json.

Comment: @NickHolden I am using it for array, it was how I get array, since I am using Sequelize.

Comment: Yes, I cannot check out the output as it seems to be the one returning SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: print this.getDataValue("service_gallery"). Can you add the result of this?

Comment: Yes, I will give iit a try, one moment pls

Comment: I did that, and it returned the following: 

"service_gallery": "\"[\\\"http://localhost:5000/uploads\\\\\\\\1604050353497-13962522_1239977336026472_3383407261859926493_n.jpg\\\",\\\"http://localhost:5000/uploads\\\\\\\\1604050353499-3b53af08b24d14b6d174a8ca7fe584d4.jpg\\\",\\\"http://localhost:5000/uploads\\\\\\\\1604050353500-53402028_3741",

Comment: Here's your problem.
json.parse() takes a string which looks like a json object, and converts it to a json object.
What you have here doesn't look like a json, or a broken one.

Comment: No, it is an array of string, and originate from array of pictures:
 service_gallery: req.files["service_gallery"].map(
              (file) => `${req.protocol}://${req.headers.host}/${file.path}`
            )

Comment: an array of string is not a json string, so json.parse will always fail in this case.

Comment: What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: It depends on what you do with the return value of service_gallery.get(). I'd start from the "bigger picture", and define what exactly I expect to receive here (type of value), and what am I going to do with it next. Then, you can change the service_gallery.get() function to whatever you need it to do/return.

Comment: The return is array of string of src (for images)

Comment: so you're basically getting a bunch of URLs you're later 'GET'ing? So just return the array as-is and use the strings for the URLs.

Comment: Yes, I tried to do it like that, but it just returned: 
  "service_gallery": "\"[\\\"http://localhost:5000/uploads\\\\\\\\1604050353497-13962522_1239977336026472_3383407261859926493_n.jpg\\\",\\\"http://localhost:5000/uploads\\\\\\\\1604050353499-3b53af08b24d14b6d174a8ca7fe584d4.jpg\\\",\\\"http://localhost:5000/uploads\\\\\\\\1604050353500-53402028_3741",

Comment: Not sure what the issue is here.
You're gonna have to debug what is the issue you encounter. Are you trying to use the array's objects but fail? Are you trying to use the URLs and the GET fails?

I think at this point you need to take a step back, understand the values you're working with, what each of the used functions is returning, and what you expect it to return.

Ask a new question if you encounter further issues, but I highly suggest you try to tackle this alone first. It will greatly assist with understanding all of this better :)

Comment: service_gallery is array of pictures that I uploaded with multer.

Comment: @NickHolden thanks, I have tried to tackle it on my own, and seems to be getting the problem. Thanks a lot